# java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call convertMessagesAsAppropriate(com.Response@1bb35b)

Tags: java, easymock

Need help is deciding what approach needs to be taken to test below piece of code

I have one method called

```
private messageDAOInf messageDAO;

public Response verifyUser(Request request) {
    Response response = null;

    if (someCondition) {
        /* -----------Some processing here---------- */
    } else {
        response = constructResponse(errorCode, errorDesc);     
    }

    // Do more processing with messages from response
    response = messageDAOInf
        .convertMessagesAsAppropriate(response);

    return response;
}
```

My EasyMock code is here

```
/** The message dao inf. */
private MessageDAOInf messageDAOInf;

private VerifyUserService verifyUserServiceI;

@Before

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    messageDAOInf = EasyMock.createMock(MessageDAOInf.class);
    verifyUserService = new VerifyUserService();
    verifyUserService.setMessageDAOInf(messageDAOInf);
}

@Test

public void testErrorResponse() {
    Request request = loadRequest();

    Response response = constructErrorResponse();

    EasyMock.expect(messageDAOInf.convertMessagesAsAppropriate(
        response)).andReturn(response);

    EasyMock.replay(messageDAOInf);

    Response response2 = verifyUserService.verifyUser(request);

    assertFailedResponse(response2);
}
```

The issue is from line

```
response = constructResponse(errorCode, errorDesc);
```

it constructs error response in verifyUser method and passes it to 
`messageDAOInf.convertMessagesAsAppropriate()`

But with easy mock it passes some other instance (mocked one) and hence failes with error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call convertMessagesAsAppropriate(***Response@1bb35b***):
    convertMessagesAsAppropriate(***Response@1b5d2b2***): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:29)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:56)
```

Let me know what approach I should take.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your initial code expects that `convertMessagesAsAppropriate` will be called with the exact **instance** of `Response` that you created in the test: obviously it will not do that.

The correction you've made is essentially the same as using the built-in `EasyMock.anyObject()` method which will allow any `Response` instance. If that's all you want to check in your unit test, that's fine. Alternatively you can add extra logic into your `ArgumentMatcher` to prove that the `Response` that is passed as an argument really is an ErrorResponse, or `Capture` the response and examine it in your test. This all depends on your level of testing :-)

Comment: To clarify, you specify the class as a parameter to `anyObject()`: `EasyMock.anyObject(Response.class)`

Answer (score 1):

I have found out way of doing it.
You need to implement interface org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher

```
public class ObjectEquals implements IArgumentMatcher {


/** The expected. */
private Object expected;

/**
 * Instantiates a new criterion equals.
 * 
 * @param expected
 *            the expected
 */
public ObjectEquals(final Object expected) {
    this.expected = expected;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher#matches(java.lang.Object)
 */
public boolean matches(final Object actual) {
    return expected.getClass().equals(actual.getClass());
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher#appendTo(java.lang.StringBuffer)
 */
public void appendTo(final StringBuffer buffer) {
    buffer.append("buffer(");
}
```

}

and in your test class add method

```
/*
     * Eq criterion.
     * 
     * @param criterion the criterion
     * 
     * @return the criterion
     */
    public static <T> T eqCriterion(final Class<T> className, Object object) {
        EasyMock.reportMatcher(new ObjectEquals(object));
        return null;
    }
```

Now while passing to easymock use method eqCriterion at line

```
EasyMock.expect(messageDAOInf.convertMessagesAsAppropriate(         
        response)).andReturn(response);
```

In short replace above line with

```
EasyMock.expect(messageDAOInf.convertMessagesAsAppropriate(         
        eqCriterion(Response.class, response))).andReturn(response);
```

This way it will use this mocked response instance instead of one generated by actual code.